# Error opening Chrome from Delphi app

Tags: google-chrome, delphi

I have a web app. I launch it from a windows app created using Delphi.
Inside my code I launch chrome using

```
ShellExecEx(ChromePath, AppStartCmd, '', SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED)
```

(https://github.com/project-jedi/jcl/blob/master/jcl/source/windows/JclShell.pas)

If the first Chrome process is the first process that I launch on my pc, if I want open another Chrome windows (for example the user start pc, launch the app and then he wants search something on google..) I have this message

[image]

Otherwise, if I first open a Chrome page and then I want launch webapp it works fine.

For a my test I made a desktop shortcut of chrome when I launch the app with same parameters

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app=http://myapppath
```

In this mode chrome works fine.

Using ProcessExplorer I have seen that launching webapp by desktop shotcut I have a recognizable process
[image]

launching the app by ShellExecEx the process is anonymous...
[image]

Comment: You should use CreateProcess instead of ShellExecute

Comment: You need to run exactly Chrome? Or it can be default system browser? Because for default browser you can run `ShellExecEx('http://site.url')` and don't mess with parameters. URL will be handled by system and default app for HTTP links will be executed.

Comment: Its not anonymous process.. its process with a higher privilege ( administrator ) use RunAs `ShellExecEx(ChromePath, AppStartCmd, 'runas', SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);` instead. or search about `ShellExecuteElevated`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instance of Chrome that your program starts evidently has elevated privileges. When the user later runs Chrome manually, it cannot communicate with the elevated copy because window messages aren't allowed to flow to higher-privileged windows. Chrome interprets that as being unresponsive.

A process inherits its privilege level from its parent, which means your program is running elevated, and that probably means you're running Delphi elevated, too. You shouldn't need to do that, so I recommend you stop.

Alternatively, you can attempt to execute the Chrome process with lower privileges than your program has. [Raymond Chen blogged about that a few years ago](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20131118-00/?p=2643) and explained that it's not trivial. He demonstrates fetching the desktop shell automation object, then getting the `IShellDispatch2` interface, and finally calling that interface's `ShellExecute` method, effectively making Explorer execute the program instead of your program executing it itself. This works because Explorer is running as the current user, not as the elevated user, so anything it executes won't be elevated, either.